# Ear Clipping Triangulator Crashing

Tags: java, geometry, libgdx

i'm struggling with a problem in ear clipping triangulator of libgdx.
It goes into infinite loop at some point and crashes the whole program.
I recorded where exactly crash occurs on [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Y43KStb6cI).

Source Code of Triangulator:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Mario Zechner (contact@badlogicgames.com), Nathan Sweet (admin@esotericsoftware.com), Nicolas Gramlich
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS"
 * BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language
 * governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.badlogic.gdx.math;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple implementation of the ear cutting algorithm to triangulate simple
 * polygons without holes. For more information:
 * http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Ian/algorithm2.html
 * http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf
 * 
 * @author badlogicgames@gmail.com
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich (Improved performance. Collinear edges are now supported.)
 */
public final class EarClippingTriangulator {

  private static final int CONCAVE = 1;
  private static final int CONVEX = -1;

  private int concaveVertexCount;

  /**
   * Triangulates the given (concave) polygon to a list of triangles. The
   * resulting triangles have clockwise order. 
   * @param polygon the polygon
   * @return the triangles
   */
  public List<Vector2> computeTriangles(final List<Vector2> polygon) {
    // TODO Check if LinkedList performs better
    final ArrayList<Vector2> triangles = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    final ArrayList<Vector2> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector2>(polygon.size());
    vertices.addAll(polygon);

    if(vertices.size() == 3) {
      triangles.addAll(vertices);
      return triangles;
    }

    while(vertices.size() >= 3) {
      // TODO Usually(Always?) only the Types of the vertices next to the ear change! --> Improve
      final int vertexTypes[] = this.classifyVertices(vertices);

      final int vertexCount = vertices.size();
      for(int index = 0; index < vertexCount; index++) {
        if(this.isEarTip(vertices, index, vertexTypes)) {
          this.cutEarTip(vertices, index, triangles);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return triangles;
  }

  private static boolean areVerticesClockwise(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices) {
    final int vertexCount = pVertices.size();

    float area = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
      final Vector2 p1 = pVertices.get(i);
      final Vector2 p2 = pVertices.get(EarClippingTriangulator.computeNextIndex(pVertices, i));
      area += p1.x * p2.y - p2.x * p1.y;
    }

    if(area < 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param pVertices
   * @return An array of length <code>pVertices.size()</code> filled with either {@link EarClippingTriangulator#CONCAVE} or
   * {@link EarClippingTriangulator#CONVEX}.
   */
  private int[] classifyVertices(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices) {
    final int vertexCount = pVertices.size();

    final int[] vertexTypes = new int[vertexCount];
    this.concaveVertexCount = 0;

    /* Ensure vertices are in clockwise order. */
    if(!EarClippingTriangulator.areVerticesClockwise(pVertices)) {
      Collections.reverse(pVertices);
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < vertexCount; index++) {
      final int previousIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, index);
      final int nextIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computeNextIndex(pVertices, index);

      final Vector2 previousVertex = pVertices.get(previousIndex);
      final Vector2 currentVertex = pVertices.get(index);
      final Vector2 nextVertex = pVertices.get(nextIndex);

      if(EarClippingTriangulator.isTriangleConvex(previousVertex.x, previousVertex.y, currentVertex.x, currentVertex.y, nextVertex.x, nextVertex.y)) {
        vertexTypes[index] = CONVEX;
      } else {
        vertexTypes[index] = CONCAVE;
        this.concaveVertexCount++;
      }
    }

    return vertexTypes;
  }

  private static boolean isTriangleConvex(final float pX1, final float pY1, final float pX2, final float pY2, final float pX3, final float pY3) {
    if(EarClippingTriangulator.computeSpannedAreaSign(pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3) < 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  private static int computeSpannedAreaSign(final float pX1, final float pY1, final float pX2, final float pY2, final float pX3, final float pY3) {
    float area = 0;

    area += pX1 * (pY3 - pY2);
    area += pX2 * (pY1 - pY3);
    area += pX3 * (pY2 - pY1);

    return (int)Math.signum(area);
  }

  /**
   * @return <code>true</code> when the Triangles contains one or more vertices, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   */
  private static boolean isAnyVertexInTriangle(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int[] pVertexTypes, final float pX1, final float pY1, final float pX2, final float pY2, final float pX3, final float pY3) {
    int i = 0;

    final int vertexCount = pVertices.size();
    while(i < vertexCount - 1) {
      if((pVertexTypes[i] == CONCAVE)) {
        final Vector2 currentVertex = pVertices.get(i);

        final float currentVertexX = currentVertex.x;
        final float currentVertexY = currentVertex.y;

        /* TODO The following condition fails for perpendicular, axis aligned triangles! 
         * Removing it doesn't seem to cause problems. 
         * Maybe it was an optimization?
         * Maybe it tried to handle collinear pieces ? */
//        if(((currentVertexX != pX1) && (currentVertexY != pY1)) || ((currentVertexX != pX2) && (currentVertexY != pY2)) || ((currentVertexX != pX3) && (currentVertexY != pY3))) {
          final int areaSign1 = EarClippingTriangulator.computeSpannedAreaSign(pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, currentVertexX, currentVertexY);
          final int areaSign2 = EarClippingTriangulator.computeSpannedAreaSign(pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, currentVertexX, currentVertexY);
          final int areaSign3 = EarClippingTriangulator.computeSpannedAreaSign(pX3, pY3, pX1, pY1, currentVertexX, currentVertexY);

          if(areaSign1 > 0 && areaSign2 > 0 && areaSign3 > 0) {
            return true;
          } else if(areaSign1 <= 0 && areaSign2 <= 0 && areaSign3 <= 0) {
            return true;
          }
//        }
      }
      i++;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean isEarTip(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int pEarTipIndex, final int[] pVertexTypes) {
    if(this.concaveVertexCount != 0) {
      final Vector2 previousVertex = pVertices.get(EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, pEarTipIndex));
      final Vector2 currentVertex = pVertices.get(pEarTipIndex);
      final Vector2 nextVertex = pVertices.get(EarClippingTriangulator.computeNextIndex(pVertices, pEarTipIndex));

      if(EarClippingTriangulator.isAnyVertexInTriangle(pVertices, pVertexTypes, previousVertex.x, previousVertex.y, currentVertex.x, currentVertex.y, nextVertex.x, nextVertex.y)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  private void cutEarTip(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int pEarTipIndex, final ArrayList<Vector2> pTriangles) {
    final int previousIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, pEarTipIndex);
    final int nextIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computeNextIndex(pVertices, pEarTipIndex);

    if(!EarClippingTriangulator.isCollinear(pVertices, previousIndex, pEarTipIndex, nextIndex)) {
      pTriangles.add(new Vector2(pVertices.get(previousIndex)));
      pTriangles.add(new Vector2(pVertices.get(pEarTipIndex)));
      pTriangles.add(new Vector2(pVertices.get(nextIndex)));
    }

    pVertices.remove(pEarTipIndex);
    if(pVertices.size() >= 3) {
      EarClippingTriangulator.removeCollinearNeighborEarsAfterRemovingEarTip(pVertices, pEarTipIndex);
    }
  }

  private static void removeCollinearNeighborEarsAfterRemovingEarTip(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int pEarTipCutIndex) {
    final int collinearityCheckNextIndex = pEarTipCutIndex % pVertices.size();
    int collinearCheckPreviousIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, collinearityCheckNextIndex);

    if(EarClippingTriangulator.isCollinear(pVertices, collinearityCheckNextIndex)) {
      pVertices.remove(collinearityCheckNextIndex);

      if(pVertices.size() > 3) {
        /* Update */
        collinearCheckPreviousIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, collinearityCheckNextIndex);
        if(EarClippingTriangulator.isCollinear(pVertices, collinearCheckPreviousIndex)){
          pVertices.remove(collinearCheckPreviousIndex);
        }
      }
    } else if(EarClippingTriangulator.isCollinear(pVertices, collinearCheckPreviousIndex)){
      pVertices.remove(collinearCheckPreviousIndex);
    }
  }

  private static boolean isCollinear(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int pIndex) {
    final int previousIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computePreviousIndex(pVertices, pIndex);
    final int nextIndex = EarClippingTriangulator.computeNextIndex(pVertices, pIndex);

    return EarClippingTriangulator.isCollinear(pVertices, previousIndex, pIndex, nextIndex);
  }

  private static boolean isCollinear(final ArrayList<Vector2> pVertices, final int pPreviousIndex, final int pIndex, final int pNextIndex) {
    final Vector2 previousVertex = pVertices.get(pPreviousIndex);
    final Vector2 vertex = pVertices.get(pIndex);
    final Vector2 nextVertex = pVertices.get(pNextIndex);

    return EarClippingTriangulator.computeSpannedAreaSign(previousVertex.x, previousVertex.y, vertex.x, vertex.y, nextVertex.x, nextVertex.y) == 0;
  }

  private static int computePreviousIndex(final List<Vector2> pVertices, final int pIndex) {
    return pIndex == 0 ? pVertices.size() - 1 : pIndex - 1;
  }

  private static int computeNextIndex(final List<Vector2> pVertices, final int pIndex) {
    return pIndex == pVertices.size() - 1 ? 0 : pIndex + 1;
  }
}
```

Crash occurs @ 53# line in the source-code linked above...
while loop in computeTriangles function with following condition  : while(vertices.size() >= 3) { ...

Comment: Here is a dirty-fix i made, it ignores any edit that causes infinite loop : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z69Fh_XpRrU

Comment: I think you should file a bug in the libgdx issue tracker for this: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your polygon needs to be *simple*, i.e. it cannot intersect itself. The `EarClippingTriangulator` javadoc states this fact. However, going into an infinite loop on invalid input is pretty bad behaviour.

That said, there are also bugs which can cause the triangulator to clip a valid, simple polygon into one that does have self-intersections, and thus get itself into an infinite loop. This can happen when points are (nearly or exactly) collinear. There are at least two bug reports about this:
[#1407](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1407) by myself, and 
[#207](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=207), which was marked fixed but was probably only fixed for some cases.

I have sent [a pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/490) that was just merged, so any libgdx release after 30 June 2013 should have fewer of these problems.